# Can't get correct width when the height is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that I can't get correct width.

I want to get the width and the height of this div with className child

```
<Parent>
    <div className={"child"} ></div>
</Parent>
```

I try to get sizes of the child with ref:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component<ParentProps, ParentState> {
    refComponent: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    constructor(_props: ParentProps) {
        super(_props);
        this.refComponent = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let me = this;
        const current = me.refComponent.current;

        if (current != null) {
            let clientRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
            let height = clientRect.height;
            let width = clientRect.width;
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me incorrect width(991) when actual width is 602.

css of div:

```
.child {
    background-color: green;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 200px 100px 20px;
}
```

I'm attaching a picture in which you can see that height is correct, but width is not

[image]

Comment: Consider putting `getBoundingClientRect()` into a variable and re-using that?

Comment: Your image isn't particularly clear, are you saying that the `991` value is incorrect? What you have selected looks like it would be the parent of the `.child` element, rather than the child itself. A [mre] would be helpful in explaining the issue.

Comment: I edited my question so I hope it's more clear now

Comment: I tried to put new variable getBoundingClientRect() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using

```
<div>
    {React.cloneElement(me.props.children, {ref: me.refComponent})}
</div>
```

in Parent class